# Reduction of coupled ODEs based on symmetry

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the following question:

Suppose I have a coupled ODEs, described by the following scheme:

[image]

$$\dot{x}_1 = f(x_1)+H(x_2);  \ \ \ \ \dot{x}_2 = f(x_2)+H(x_3)+H(x_1);  \ \ \ \ \dot{x}_3 = f(x_3)+H(x_2);  $$

where $f$ and $H$ could be **nonlinear function**.

Now based on that scheme, obviously, node $1$ and $3$ are symmetric and both of them make no difference for the node $2$.  So reduce the above three ODEs to the following by renaming a different variable $y$: 
$$\dot{y}_1 = f(y_1)+H(y_2);  \ \ \ \ \dot{y}_2 = f(y_2)+2H(y_1);  $$

i.e., I combine nodes $1$ and $3$ to a new node $1$. More precisely, $x_1$ and $x_3$ are replaced by $y_1$, $x_2$ is replaced by $y_2$

My question is:

1. Can I say both systems ($x$ and $y$) are equivalent?
2. Solution behavior around equilibrium points are the same, such as region of attraction?

Can anyone please give me some directions or related article about questions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Your replacement only makes sense if $x_1$ and $x_3$ have the same initial condition.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks! I will be careful on this.

Comment: @MichaelLee One more question, should the region of attraction be the same? for example $x_2$ and $y_2$. I think ROA depends on $f$ and $H$, looks like $x_2$ and $y_2$ should have the same ROA.

Comment: The system that you have written is absolutely correct on the invariant manifold $x_1 = x_3$. If you want to study what happens on that invariant manifold, you can use it without any hesitation. You also probably see that symmetry of equations implies the symmetry of solutions: for any solution $(X_1(t), X_2(t), X_3(t))$ follows that $(X_3(t), X_2(t), X_1(t))$ is also a solution. By the way, you probably will want to study system on invariant manifold later or sooner. The good property is that $x_1 = x_3$ divides the space: a trajectory can't go from $x_1 > x_3$ to $x_1 < x_3$ because of it.